# Struct inside struct: char[] assignment

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct inside a struct, how can I assign the insert function parameter as a value of the name element

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct func{
    int matric;         
    char name[120];     
    char phone[80];     
    float sal;
}Func;

struct arv {
    Func* info;
    struct arv* esq;
    struct arv* dir;
};
typedef struct arv Arv;


void insert(Arv ** tree, char str[120])
{
    Arv *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (Arv *)malloc(sizeof(Arv));
        temp->esq = temp->dir = NULL;
        temp->info->name = str;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }
}
```

In temp->info->name = str , i hav the error: the expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: Note that since info is a Func pointer you also need to allocate space for Func. `temp->info = malloc(sizeof(Func))`.

Comment: OT: the `(Arv *)` cast in `(Arv *)malloc(sizeof(Arv))` is useless, just write `temp = malloc(sizeof(Arv))`, or even better `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp))`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing "array assignment" in c, you would have to use a function like `strcpy` from `string.h` in order to copy the name:

```
strcpy(temp->info->name, str);
```

In addition, I would suggest to put `typedef struct arv Arv;` declaration above the `struct arv` and then define it like so:

```
struct arv
{
    Func* info;
    Arv* esq;
    Arv* dir;
};
```

Please note that you did not allocate memory for `Func`, and you will most likely get a segmentation fault.